# almost sure Properties of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

What's the difference between

> "A stochastic process has infinitely many zeros in every interval
>   **almost surely**."

and

> "A stochastic process has infinitely many zeros in every interval."

?

In my opinion there is no difference since an interval is no P-nullset. 
I'm trying to imagine paths of Brownian motions. But if the two statements above mean the same you couldn't image any Brownian path. But it's not easy for me since most properties are almost surely. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'... an interval is no P-null set...': You are confusing the Lebesgue measure on the time line with the underlying probability measure.

A real-valued stochastic process is a measurable mapping from a probability space, $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ to the set of real-valued functions equipped with a proper sigma algebra.

The first statement means this: If you collect every $\omega \in \Omega$ such that the function $X(\omega)$ has infinitely many zeros in every interval, the resulting set is an element of $\mathcal{F}$ and that it has measure $1$.

The second statement means this: For every $\omega \in \Omega$, the function $X(\omega)$ has infinitely many zeros in every interval.

Comment: I don't get the difference. For instance we consider the standard Brownian motion $B_t$, where the probability measure is the Wiener measure. The Wiener measure is Gaussian. There is no interval that is a nullset wrt the gaussian measures, only (unions of) point sets. So  the two statements would be the same.

Comment: @lemontree I don't know which construction(s) of Brownian motion you are familiar with but one construction is as follows. You first come up with the finite dimensional distributions of Brownian motion (based on the distributional properties in its definition. no path properties here). Then you invoke Kolmogorov's extension theorem to show that a stochastic *process* with those distributional properties exists. That is not yet Brownian motion. Next you invoke Kolmogorov-Centov to show that a continuous modification of the process in the first step exists.

Comment: @lemontree So you can very well have a process with Gaussianity with no control over paths.

Comment: A last question: There are paths of Brownian motion which don't have infinitely many zeros in any interval $[0,\varepsilon]$. For instance fix $\omega \in \Omega$ and consider $t\to B_t(\omega)$. Then it could be that $B_t(\omega)$ doesnt't have infinitely many zeros since $P(\{\omega: B_t \text{ has not infinitely many zeros}\})=P(\{\omega\})=0$. Am I right?